# How to make Sublime Text 3 opening your last file/folder when started?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, preferences

I'm on Mac running Yosemite. I use Sublime Text 3.

In my default Settings, I have it like this :

```
"hot_exit": true,
"remember_open_files": true,
```

When I close a window and reopen it back, my old open files/folder didn't come back. Quit it, Reopen it - still didn't recall anything back.

I don't want that.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In order for `hot_exit` and `remember_open_files` to work, you can't just close the window by clicking on the red dot - you need to completely quit Sublime with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, ***while the windows are still open***. If you close a window, its contents are gone.

Comment: Ohh I see. I will try that now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Dogoku that's how Macs work, and have *always* worked. Personally, I find it annoying on PCs when I close a window, then have to start the whole program again. It's a design decision made by the OS architects.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this in your setting:

"create_window_at_startup": false,

It helped in my case...

Comment: Not in mine though: meaning if you close the window with red dot. No old content is restored on restarting Sublime (3). Accepted answer works, close sublime with CMD+Q and reloading works, at least with those 2 user settings defined.